# sqlitexception logic error or missing database no such table:nam

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am very new to sqlite to be used in C#. So I created the db in the bin folder. I create a class below.

```
class myCon{
  public SQLiteConnection GetConnection(){
    string str = @"Data Source=gf.sqlite3";
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    return con;
  }
}
```

Then I call it as below to test my insert

```
try {
  myCon getMyCon1 = new myCon();
  SQLiteConnection con = getMyCon1.GetConnection();

  string sql = "insert into nam (Id, test1) values ('3000')";
  SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I have confirmed using the gui browser that the table and db is there. I just can't figure out what is wrong?

Comment: In what directory is the DB file stored?

Comment: Same with the bin. But I want to set a relative path is that possible?

Comment: You are *already* using a relative path (which is relative to a random directory).

Comment: Ok once I need to deployment I want the exe and .sqlite3 to be in separate folder? I google a lot of them keep in appdata? How to set that ?

Comment: By specifying the path.

Comment: If I specify the path isnt it will become static? Any example ?

Comment: I've heard rumors that C# supports string variables.

Comment: Is there any example what path to specified?